# Upgrading to Powershell 5.1 from 3.0

Tags: windows, powershell, upgrade

I want to upgrade my Windows PowerShell to version 5.1 from version 3.0 on Windows 7. The installation instruction says Powershell 3.0 is to be uninstalled or to save the PSModulePath and then restore it manually after WMF 5.1 installation is complete.

How do I save the PSModulepath and continue with the installation?

Answer (score 1):

`PSModulePath` is an environment variable, to get the current system-wide value and export it, you could do:

```
[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('PSModulePath', 'Machine') |Set-Content C:\path\to\PSModulePath.v3.txt
```

In case it isn't set correctly after the installation/upgrade, import and set it again with:

```
$modulePath = Get-Content C:\path\to\PSModulePath.v3.txt
[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('PSModulePath', $modulePath, 'Machine')
```

... from an elevated prompt